# Interpolating polynomial Problem. Show that $p(3) = 1.25$

Tags: polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

My Question is:

Suppose that p(x) is the cubic polynomial that interpolates

[image]
.

in which $a ∈ [−2, 4].$

Show that $p(3) = 1.25$ in the case where $a = 0$

Ive been trying to do this question for a couple of hours but i seem to always get $3$ as my answer instead of $1.25.$ So if anyone could help me get to $1.25$ that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$L_0 = -\frac{1}{264}x(x-5)(x-8)$$
$$L_1 = \frac{1}{120}(x+3)(x-5)(x-8)$$
$$L_3 = \frac{1}{264}x(x+3)(x-5)$$
and you get
$$p(3)=L_0+3L_1+0L_2+L_3=1.25$$

[Wolframalpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D-x(x-5)(x-8)%2F264%2B3*(x%2B3)(x-5)(x-8)%2F120%2B(x%2B3)(x-5)x%2F264,%20solve%20for%20x%3D3)